# Why this simple php session doesn't work?

Tags: php, session

My session mechanism seems broken, so I tried with this very short code. What's wrong here? Am I missing something?

index.php

```
<?php session_start();?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        echo '<form action="update.php?'.  session_id().'" method="POST"><fieldset><input type="text" value="hello"/><input type="submit" value="OK"/></fieldset></form>';
        print_r($_SESSION);
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

update.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    print_r($_POST);
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
        $_SESSION[$key]=$value;
    session_write_close();
    print_r($_SESSION);
?>

<a href="index.php?<?php echo session_id();?>">hello</a>
```

Comment: Define 'broken'. Define 'doesn't work'.

Comment: What's the error message supplied with your conclusion that "it does't work".

Comment: Simply the fact that print_r returns empty Arrays where it shouldn't.

Comment: I would recommend using braces with your foreach loop, so everything possible is written to the session super global. `foreach($key => $Val){ ..... } session_write_close();` to avoid possible clashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your post is not working, likely it's because your from inputs have no names:

**index.php**

```
<?php session_start();?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
        <form action="update.php" method="POST">
                <fieldset>
                    <input type="hidden" name="session_key" value="<?php echo session_id(); ?>" />
                    <input type="text" name="message" value="hello"/>
                    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="OK"/>
                </fieldset>
        </form>

        <?php  print_r($_SESSION); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**update.php**

```
    session_start();
    print_r($_POST);
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    session_write_close();
    print_r($_SESSION);

<a href="index.php?id=<?php echo session_id();?>">hello</a>
```

Comment: You have found the possible solution, though.. printing $_SESSION on the form page is a bad idea, if empty. It'll show `array()`. If this is just for debugging purposes, add a comment next to it to remove in production.